# Cannot open Jupyter Notebook in the new zsh shell in macOS

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell, zsh

I recently upgraded to macOS Catalina and it prompted me to upgrade to the zsh shell. But now when I try to run `jupyter notebook`, it says command not found. I tried looking for it in `.bashrc` but `.bashrc` does not exist. What do I do? I did `pip install jupyter` on the home /Users/username and I am using python3.

Comment: How did you install Jupyter in the first place? Which Python distribution are you running currently? The built-in one, or Homebrew, or some other package? `.bashrc` is not usually used on macOS, and anyway it isn't what ZSH would read.

Comment: It was working fine until before I updated the default shell. I could go to the terminal and type in ```jupyter notebook``` and it would launch.

Comment: I know, you mentioned that in your question. My question was how you installed Jupyter (and Python) in the first place? Jupyter is not shipped with macOS.

Comment: Also, please edit your question and provide the following info: Can you check if `/usr/local/bin/jupyter` exists? What does `echo $PATH` show?

Comment: I did ```pip install jupyter```. And, no the  ```/usr/local/bin/jupyter``` does not exist. ```echo $PATH``` shows ```/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin```

Comment: It would be better if you could [edit] your question to include this info. What happens when you now run `pip install jupyter`? And, sorry, I have to ask again, what kind of Python distribution are you using?

Comment: It says the requirement already satisfied. I am running python3.

Comment: And where did you get `python3`? Via Homebrew? Does `pip3 install jupyter` work? If you have an additional Python 3 version installed, you might need `pip3` to install packages with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is some additional configuration that you need to do to get it to work.

1. Open bash profile using the command:

   ```
   open ~/.bash_profile
   ```
2. There’s a block of code the anaconda installer added to the end of the file. Copy that. It looks something like this

   [image]
3. Open the `.zshrc` file:

   ```
   open ~/.zshrc
   ```

   And paste the copied code to the end of the file and save it.
4. Restart the terminal:

   ```
   source ~/.zshrc
   ```

Comment: It gives me The file /Users/sarawasl/.zshrc does not exist. at step 3

Comment: @LamaMo hopefully solved it by now, but for others who might have the same issue: the ~/.zshrc doesn’t exist by default in macOS so you need to create it by e.g. ```nano ~/.zshrc```

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the similar annoying problem and here is my one-line solution:

- Open terminal and type:

  ```
  brew install jupyter
  ```
- If you haven't install `brew` on your Mac, please follow the instruction here: https://brew.sh/

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
  ```
- Wait for around *10* minutes until the installation finishes and try `jupyter` again.

---

Explain:

It helps download a lot of "Catalina" related packages, like

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/jupyterlab-2.1.5.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
......
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ipython-7.16.1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
......
```

See
https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/34
for the latest discussions on this issue.

Comment: Excellent response, this did the update to use jupyter on zsh. You will still need to run `brew link` with the overwrite option for ipython and jupyter; and also run `brew cleanup` after, but this is the way

Answer (score 1):

```bash
sudo -H pip3 install jupyter
```

`-H` (HOME) sets the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the target user (root by default).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If it was working before you just need to change the default shell to Bash. You can do that by running the following code in the terminal.

`chsh -s /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Running python or jupyter-notebook via **pyenv**, then this answer is for you.
(i.e. python/jupyter-notebook is installed inside `/Users/<hostname>/.pyenv` directory. See [this](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) to install pyenv)

After installing the `oh-my-zsh` shell:

1. Open the .zshrc file in a text-editor -> `open ~/.zshrc`
2. Append **pyenv** in its list like ->

   `plugins=(git node rails pyenv)`

   *ohmyzsh provides various plugins w.r.t different languages & framewroks. Search for the plugins section in the .zshrc file and append pyenv there.*

3. Launch a new instance of your zsh-terminal. Now, your zsh terminal instance will be able to detect pyenv and the packages installed inside it.
4. Now, check for the **jupyter** -> `which jupyter`. You'll see the path where jupyter is installed on machine.

   Or, simply launch jupyter on terminal-> `jupyter notebook`.

   Notebook will open up in your favorite browser!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is to do with the '.bash_profile' file not being recognised by Zsh. Instead Zsh needs a '.zshrc' file. To fix simply follow these steps:

1. Open Finder and navigate to /Users/{YourUser}/
2. Press "Shift + Command + ." to show hidden files

**If you DO NOT see a '.zshrc' file:**

3. Make a copy of the '.bash_profile' file
4. Rename the copy '.zshrc'

**If you DO see a '.zshrc' file:**

3. Open the '.bash_profile' file using TextEditor
4. Copy the string after "PATH=" i.e. "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:"
5. Paste that string to within the '.zshrc' file after "PATH="

**Now open a new Zsh terminal and type 'jupyter-notebook'. This should resolve the $PATH issues and execute the script.**

Ofcourse, you could do all the above steps within the Zsh terminal but I find it more confusing for the average user.

Answer (score -1):

Zsh does not use `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` it uses `~/.zshrc` instead.

Executing this command **in bash** will add a line to your `~/.zshrc` that should fix your issue:

```
echo 'PATH=${PATH}:'"$(dirname "$(which jupyter)")" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Breakdown of what the command does:

1. Lookup path of `jupyter` (`which jupyter`)
2. Take directory from the path from step 1 (`dirname path_from_step_1`)
3. Construct a line that adds this directory to your `$PATH` env variable (`PATH=${PATH}:directory_path_from_step_2`)
4. Append the line to end of your `~/.zshrc` (`echo the_line_from_step_3 >> ~/.zshrc`)

Basically, the command above asks bash where is `jupyter` and then tells zsh to also search there when looking for programs and executables. That means that if `jupyter` works in your bash it should work in your zsh after this.

*I don't have a Mac to test this on so if this doesn't work please leave a comment so I can debug this and figure out a solution.*

Comment: This did not work, also the output was "usage: dirname path" suggesting it is doing the wrong kind of thing

Comment: Can you run `which jupyter` and post the output?